# Lower bound on the distance fom a point to the border of a region.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to prove the following result in complex analysis:

> If $f $ is an analytic and bijective function from the unit disc to an open connected region $A$ then the distance from $f(0)$ to the the border of $A$ is at least $|f'(0)|$.

The theorems I think I have to use are Schwarz Lemma and the Maximum Modulus Principle, but I can't find a good way to put it all together for this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that it shouldn't be "at most $|f'(0)|$"? – $f(z) = (1-z)/(1+z)$ maps the unit disk conformally to the right halfplane, and $f'(0) = 2$. The distance of $f(0)$ to the border is $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, the distance from $f(0)$ to the border of $A$ is
*at most* $|f'(0)|$:

Assume that $B_d(f(0)) \subset A$. Then
$$
 h(z) = f^{-1}(f(0) + dz) 
$$ 
maps the unit disk $\Bbb D$ into itself with $h(0) = 0$, and
$$
h'(z) = \frac{d}{f'(f^{-1}(f(0) + dz)} \, .
$$
Applying the Schwarz Lemma to $h$ gives
$$
 1 \ge |h'(0)| = \frac{d}{|f'(0)|}
$$
and therefore $d \le |f'(0)|$.

A *lower bound* of the distance from $f(0)$ to the boundary of $A$ is $\frac 14 |f'(0)|$
according to the
[Koebe quarter theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem).

Comment: how did you get the d into the derivative of h?

Comment: @MathemKristel The chain rule. $d$ is the derivative of the inner function $z \to f(0)+dz $.

Comment: oh, I get it! at first I thought dz was a partial derivative. Sorry, I got confused.

Comment: @MathemKristel: No problem! $d$ is the radius of the disk $B_d(f(0))$, $d$ for "distance".